# Can't connect to my Oracle database from a SQLAPI++ program in C++

Tags: c++, oracle, sqlapi++

I'm kinda new to using database. I've been learning oracle sql and have installed oracle express edition 18c from their site. I generally perform sql queries through the provided SQL*Plus tool. Now, i really want to be able to connect to the database from my c++ program for a project. I heard about odbc and I went and downloaded the odbc drivers and instant client for my oracle version from their site. Then i found a 3rd party library called SQLAPI++ which can be used to connect to the database with c++. I downloaded and included the library in my project. I'm using codeblocks IDE on windows 10. I tried to run this program to test whether i can connect to the database-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<SQLAPI.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SAConnection conn;
    try
    {
        conn.Connect("Data Source=LIBRARY;User Id=my_uid;Password=my_pass;Integrated Security=no","my_uid","my_pass",SA_Oracle_Client);
//LIBRARY is my dsn that i created by using the odbc 64-bit admin. tool in the user dsn tab. I used the "Oracle in instantclient_18_5" driver for it.
        if(conn.isConnected()==TRUE)
        {
            cout<<"Connected successfully"<<endl;
            conn.Disconnect();
            cout<<"Disconnected successfully"<<endl;
        }
        else
            cout<<"Failed to connect"<<endl;
    }
    catch(SAException &a)
    {

        cout<<endl<<a.ErrText().GetMultiByteChars()<<endl;
    }
}
```

There are no compiler errors or warnings. Now it prints--"ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified". Any help would be greatly appreciated! >.<

Edit: Now that i run the debugger, this is what i see-

```
Setting breakpoints
Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.9.1
Child process PID: 15224
In __cxa_throw () ()
1094    oraAPI.cpp: No such file or directory.
#1  0x00494eb2 in oraAPI::Check (this=0x1307fe8, sCommandText=..., status=-1, hndlp=0x95f208, type=2, pOCIStmt=0x0) at oraAPI.cpp:1094
In __cxa_get_globals () ()
#3  0x00494c06 in oraAPI::Check (this=0x1307fe8, status=-1, hndlp=0x95f208, type=2, pOCIStmt=0x0) at oraAPI.cpp:1018
1018    in oraAPI.cpp
Cannot open file: ../../../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c
At ../../../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c:126
Cannot open file: ../../../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c
At ../../../../../src/gcc-5.1.0/libgcc/unwind-sjlj.c:128
In __cxa_get_globals () ()
1730    SQLAPI.cpp: No such file or directory.
#7  0x004054bb in SAConnection::NativeAPI (this=0x5710b2 <__DTOR_LIST__+306>) at SQLAPI.cpp:1730
In __cxa_throw () ()
1018    oraAPI.cpp: No such file or directory.
#2  0x00494c06 in oraAPI::Check (this=0x1307fe8, status=-1, hndlp=0x95f208, type=2, pOCIStmt=0x0) at oraAPI.cpp:1018
[Inferior 1 (process 15224) exited normally]
Debugger finished with status 0
```

Comment: How do you know that "this program just terminates at the conn.Connect() call"? What did you see when you ran your program, one line at a time, in your debugger?

Comment: At the line 8- SAConnection conn, it says "cannot open file SQLAPI.cpp" oh darn...i didn't run debugger before all this time huh....

Comment: Well, then the issue is not that the program "just terminates". It doesn't even compile. There is a big difference between a compilation error, and a runtime error. In order to get a helpful answer, you need to ask an accurate question.

Comment: And when you read Oracle's documentation for `SAConnection::Connect`, what documentation do you see for its parameters? The shown code does not appear to match Oracle's documentation, for `Connect()`, and should not have been compiled.

Comment: I don't understand. I did see the documentation. It takes SAString objects as parameters but can also take const char* . The example given used _TSA() macro with the strings. I also tried with it but got the same result. Plz tell me what i'm doing wrong here :(

Comment: I am unable to find any evidence of an overload that takes a `const char *` parameter. [Where in the document of Connect()](https://www.sqlapi.com/ApiDoc/class_s_a_connection.html#a27d8634e9b49349915a3fb44c22cc54e) do you see the `const char *` overload documented?

Comment: [Here](https://www.sqlapi.com/ApiDoc/class_s_a_string.html) It says "This allows you to substitute, for example, an const char* where a SAString object is expected.". So i thought it meant i could use a const char* as well

Comment: This looks like a case of binary API incompatibility. SQLAPI++'s instructions specify that after downloading it should be rebuilt by your C++ compiler. C++ libraries can only be used with the same compiler that was used to built them. It's unclear which C++ Oracle used to build SQLAPI++, so it always needs to be recompiled by the C++ compiler you're using.

Comment: But it says to use the batch files and that they are in the src directory. The unlicensed,i.e., free version doesn't include that directory.....

Comment: There's nothing you can do, then. It must be built for a specific C++ compiler, that's different than the one you're using, and that's the only compiler you can use those libraries with, then.

Comment: I changed some linker settings. Updated the question

Comment: A side question: why not use Oracle'a own C++ API "Oracle C++ Call Interface" or it's native C API "Oracle Call Interface"?  The latter has a wider feature set so is often recommended and used in C++ programs - and won't have the compiler dependency mentioned in earlier comments.  See https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/oci.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm a total noob at this but i'll post what worked for me anyway. I didn't manage to use odbc to connect to my oracle 18c database in the end but occi did the trick. I used SA_Oracle_Client as the 4th parameter and "host_name:port_no/service_name" as the connect string(1st parameter). These values i just copied from the tnsnames.ora file. Before this, i had to setup the environment variable, TNS_ADMIN to point to the directory of tnsnames.ora in the oracle_home installation folder and install the 32-bit instantclient since my compiler is 32-bit but my system, oracle installation and the previous instantclient i had downloaded were all 64-bit. Thanks to all who helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be missing references specific to the oracle use case

```
#include "oraAPI.h"
IsaAPI *pApi = con.NativeAPI();
oraAPI *pNativeAPI = (oraAPI *)pApi;
```